# Proving an integral inequality

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

> The function $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, $\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=0$ and $\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=1$. Prove that $$\frac{-5}{4}< \int_{0}^{1}e^xf(x)dx< \frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: Any thoughts yourself? What is the source? Also, why did you add the tags linear-algebra and abstract-algebra. As you see, three people have already voted to close this question, and I think these points are the main reasons (I have not voted, yet).

Comment: @mickep now four

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $$\int_{0}^{1}e^xf(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}(e^x-x)f(x)dx.$$
Hence, since $e^x>x$ in $[0,1]$, it follows that
$$-\int_{0}^{1}(e^x-x)|f(x)|dx\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^xf(x)dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}(e^x-x)|f(x)|dx.$$
Since $\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=1$, we have that
$$-M\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^xf(x)dx\leq M$$
where $M=\int_{0}^{1}(e^x-x)dx$.

Comment: Hey, could you add something more, I dont get how to proceed further. And could you also elaborate on how you thought of this, as in how should one proceed on seeing such questions. Thank you :)

Comment: @OsheenSachdev It remains to evaluate $M$ and compare it with the given bounds.

Comment: Right...okay got it, thanks!